# How to serialize/pickle a spacy ner model?

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy

I have trained a custom SpaCy named entity recognition model. I saved the model to disk using:

```
nlp.to_disk()
```

which results in keeping the model in a folder. Is it possible to make the nlp object to a pickle file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - Here is how to pickle in Python:

```py
import pickle

pickle.dump(nlp, open( "nlp.p", "wb" ))
```